# Null pointer when calling MSSQL 2008 stored procedure from Hibernate 4

Tags: sql-server-2008, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have a mapped stored procedure

```
<sql-query name="sproc" callable="true" >
    <return alias="suppliers" class="model.Supplier">
        <return-property name="name" column="CoName" />
    </return>
    { call sproc(:p1,:p2,:p3}
</sql-query>
```

When executed as a named query and the stored procedure returns results then `query.list()` will return the expected results but when the stored procedure returns no results I get a NPE when Hibernate is trying to initialize the entity to return.

I could catch the npe and return an empty list but that's not great, is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#sp_query) the mssql stored procedure must return a result set. Further in section 16.2.2.1 it states you can use session.connection(). But I don't think that will be of much use. Hence handling the null pointer seems a good way.

**EDIT :**

If you are using `session.connection()`, you can also return the `@@ROWCOUNT` if the output is the only thing that is being used in the procedure to get the number of rows changed. 0 indicating nothing being returned